# Finding actual type parameters in Java

Tags: java, generics

I have a class

```
class ClassA<B extends ClassC>
{
................
}
```

In another class I have a list of objects of type A.

```
List<A<?>> cl = new ArrayList<A<?>>();
cl.add(new ClassB1(....));
```

where ClassB1 extends ClassC. How can I find out the type of objects in the list? i.e. The first object in the list is of type ClassB1.

Adding actual code

```
ClassA<ClassB1> af = new ClassA<ClassB1>(); 
List<ClassA<?>> afl = new ArrayList<ClassA<?>>(); 
afl.add(af); 
for(ClassA<?> a: afl) 
    System.out.println(a.getClass());
```

This prints only ClassA and not ClassB1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put objects of different classes, you can iterate the list and use `getClass()`.

Update: this information is lost at runtime due to type erasure. So you can't get it.

Comment: Unrelated to the question or the answer, but since SO has no PM mechanism... Grats on 100k, Bozho! :-)

Comment: getClass() only tells me that objects are of type ClassC.

Comment: @athena - and what more do you need to know?

Comment: that, for eg, the first object is of type ClassB1.

Comment: @arthena - if the class is of type ClassB1, then it will return `CalssB1`. Perhaps your problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: @Bozho: Please see the modified question. My earlier comment was wrong, ClassA is printed not ClassC.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the class with `getClass()` if you really, really, realllllyyy need to.

However, I would advise you to reconsider the notion of needing to get the class in the first place. **If you're going to treat the classes differently, it probably isn't as generic as you think**. Consider refactoring to a more appropriate approach.